# Given a class of forms, how do I disable input in the one that was clicked using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

```
<form class="formClass">
    <input type="checkbox" class="formCheck">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<form class="formClass">
    <input type="checkbox" class="formCheck">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Given the above forms, is it possible to disable the corresponding checkbox once the form is submitted using jquery?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `submit` event of the form and then use DOM traversal to `disable` all the input elements within it, something like this:

```
$('.formClass').submit(function() {
    $(this).find('input').prop('disabled', true); // disable all <input> elements

    // alternative
    // $(this).find(':checkbox').prop('disabled', true); // disable checkbox only
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
           $(".formClass input[type=submit]").on("click",function(){
             $(this).prev('input').attr("disabled","disabled");
           });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="formClass">
    <input type="checkbox" class="formCheck">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<form class="formClass">
    <input type="checkbox" class="formCheck">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: When you click on a checkbox, it will also disable the checkbox. Using that way, you should also specify input `type` in your code

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible.I used `e.preventDefault()` to view how checkbox is changed.

```
$('.formClass').submit(function(e){
    $(this).find('.formCheck').prop('disabled',true);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j06mL2xs/)